# DataTables Ajax Load Callback

Tags: jquery, ajax, datatables

I've got a DataTable that gets its data via AJAX, and alongside the *data* member of the JSON object I have an additional *info* field that is used to determine e.g. row colors.

I'm making use of this info field fine via the [ajax.reload](https://datatables.net/reference/api/ajax.reload()) callback, but this callback isn't called on the initial table load. I tried using the XHR handler, but that's called before the table is drawn, so I've got my hands on the JSON object but not the yet-to-be-rendered table internals.

Can anyone point me to an example of a callback function that has access to the JSON object after the initial table draw operation? I.E. much the same as [ajax.reload](https://datatables.net/reference/api/ajax.reload()), only without the "re"?

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

As you mentioned in response to Angelo's answer, use the [`initComplete`](https://datatables.net/reference/option/initComplete) option.

```js
$('#example').dataTable( {
  "initComplete": function(settings, json) {
    var info = json.info;
    // do whatever with info here...
  }
} );
```

Answer (score 1):

You may use the `drawCallback` function as documented here https://datatables.net/reference/option/drawCallback

Otherwise you may use the "columnDefs" function e try to get the full row and ad to it your css. For example (not tested but it should work)

```
$("#myTable").DataTable({

                    "deferRender": true,
                    "columnDefs": 
                    [
                        {
                            "render": function ( data, type, row ) 
                            {
                                var tr = $(this).closest('tr');
                                //Now yuo should have the row
},
                            "className":"colonnaElencoMessaggi",
                            "name":"deviceMessages",
                            "orderable":false,
                            "targets": 2
                        }
                    ]
                });
```

I hope this can help

Angelo

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. It doesn't look like drawCallback is passed the JSON response, although I now notice initComplete does, which I'd somehow not come across when searching earlier, so I'll maybe try that.

Comment: I didn't check but in the documentation here https://datatables.net/reference/option/drawCallback there is the example where you can use the api() function. Maybe it can be useful